# Accessing nested dict keys and values simultaneously

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have this nested dictionary as below. Is there a pythonic way of iterating over keys and values of both outer and inner dictionaries simultaneously?

I currently perform:

```
for outer_key, outer_value in outer.items():
    for inner_key, inner_value in outer_value.items():
        #my required processing
```

Just want to know if there is any better, faster way to do this? Faster in the sense of using dict comprehensions, speedier execution than the normal method, memory savings etc (when it is applied to huge dicts)?

```
{'68299-6030-885-42-4-54603-20645-15734': {'0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0': {'service_latency': 9.815000000000001, 
                                                               'service_cost': 58.78,     
                                                               'service_bandwidth': 247.36}}, 
 '68299-6030-885-431-43303-80233-26504-15734': {'0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0': {'service_latency': 10.706, 
                                                                    'service_cost': 50.06, 
                                                                    'service_bandwidth': 362.88}}, 
 '68299-6030-885-42-79805-13540-5668-15734': {'0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0': {'service_latency': 12.66, 
                                                                  'service_cost': 75.19, 
                                                                  'service_bandwidth': 707.74}}, 
 '68299-6030-90241-3290-2033-5668-15734': {}, 
 '68299-73365-46658-104-10-6685-29853-44799': {'0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0': {'service_latency': 12.427, 
                                                                   'service_cost': 44.949999999999996,  
                                                                   'service_bandwidth': 232.89}}}
```

Comment: I would say that is the pythonic way! Why do you ask the question; are you having performance problems?

Comment: @jonrsharpe : Not really, but since I was using this in the middle of some code that itself had multiple nested loops, I just wanted to make sure that I was doing it right and not missing something entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `some_dict.items()` is appropriate method to get access to both keys and values simultaneously
- the explicit nested loops in your code may be faster than the corresponding list/dict comprehensions on CPython
- `.items()` on Python 3 doesn't create a list. It doesn't matter how huge your `dict` is: memory usage should be constant while you are iterating over `.items()`

`.items()` returns [a view](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) on Python 3. You shouldn't try to change `outer`, `outer_value` dictionaries while iterating over them.

Your code is fine as is if you can't change the input data structures.